# Npm package installation fails - how to restore the old working version?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, package-managers

It seems that failed installations attempts with `npm` delete old versions without installing new ones, which is very frustrating.

Can I go back to the old package version that worked?

I get this error:

```
gulp
-bash: /usr/local/bin/gulp: No such file or directory
```

But I can see I still have old versions of Gulp installed. Any way I can make the accessible via command line (put it manually in `/user/local/bin` ?) them until the issue with new version is fixed?

Can't do anything now with gulp!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Command line give the following find command: `sudo find / -name gulp`
It will ask for superuser password which you should enter.

This will search for the `gulp` bin file in the system.

If the search is successful then you can copy the bin file to `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Thanks, it seems that `npm` creates a symbolic link: `/usr/local/bin/gulp -> ../lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js`, simply copying binary over doesn't seem to work (executing leads to errors).

Comment: Try to give absolute path for symbolic link instead of relative path, hope then it will link to the proper file. If it doesn't work then you can try to re install 'gulp' using its source code or Debian package

Answer (score 1):

this fixed it for me:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/gulp /usr/local/bin/gulp
```